# How to get aggregation for dynamic/unknown fields in ElasticSearch 6.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a list of documents as below. I need aggregates for  field names(i.e. color, size etc) that I don't know at query time because the field names are very diverse. How can I get aggregates for these fields?

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test product 1",
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "color",
        "value": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "name": "size",
        "value": "M"
      },
      {
        "name": "height",
        "value": 124,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Test product 1",
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "color",
        "value": "Red"
      },
      {
        "name": "wifi",
        "value": "ac/g/n"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm looking for something as below. Note that `"features.name => value"` is not a real/valid notation in ES.

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "features" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "features.name => value" }
        }
    }
}
```

and a response like this

```
{
    ...
    "aggregations" : {
        "genres" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
            "buckets" : {"color": [ 
                      {
                        "key" : "red",
                        "doc_count" : 6
                       },
                       {
                       "key" : "blue",
                       "doc_count" : 3
                       },
                     ],
                {"size": [ 
                      {
                        "key" : "M",
                        "doc_count" : 6
                       },
                ],
                {"wifi": [ 
                      {
                        "key" : "ac/g/n",
                        "doc_count" : 1
                       },
                ]
        }
    }
}
```